# [ROS2] Is there a better way to mix LaunchConfiguration with simple 'str'?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
This is how I launch [xacro](https://github.com/ros/xacro) right now:

```
    xacro = Node(
        package='xacro',
        node_executable='xacro',
        node_namespace=LaunchConfiguration(args.MODEL_NAME_ARG),
        arguments=[
            [
                launch.substitutions.TextSubstitution(
                    text=get_package_share_directory('robot_description') + '/models/'),
                LaunchConfiguration(args.MODEL_ARG),
                launch.substitutions.TextSubstitution(text='/'),
                LaunchConfiguration(args.MODEL_ARG),
                launch.substitutions.TextSubstitution(text='.xacro'),
            ],
            '-o',
            urdf,
        ],
)
```

Resulting path looks like `./install/robot_description/share/robot_description/models/my_model/my_model.xacro`.
Not related to just xacro, is there a <strike>human readable</strike> better way to do such substitution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334341/%5Bros2%5D-is-there-a-better-way-to-mix-launchconfiguration-with-simple-%27str%27?/) by [Dmitriy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45566/dmitriy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-10-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2019-11-21**:
Hi @Dmitriy, did you manage to find a way around this?  I cant find a way to substitute the value of the argument as a string.

```
 DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'urdf',
        default_value='file.urdf',
        description='urdf file name')

 urdf_path =os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_bringup'), 'urdf',
                            LaunchConfiguration('urdf'))
```

[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'LaunchConfiguration'

https://answers.ros.org/question/322636/ros2-access-current-launchconfiguration/

I tried the suggestion there  "The launch argument's value is stored in the "Launch Configurations", and those can be accessed using a substitution called `launch.substitution.LaunchConfiguration(name) -> string`" but LaunchConfiguration doesnt seem to be a member of launch.substitution in Dashing.

**Comment by [Dmitriy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45566/dmitriy/) on 2019-11-22**:
@fastestindian
There are different packages `launch.substitution` and `launch.substitutions`. The latter is the one you need:

```
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
```

I guess there is a typo in the answer you mention.

---

Note you cannot use `os.path.join` until LaunchConfiguration will be substantiated, i.e. will have context of the actual launch. This is my original problem. :( Substantiation can be accessed only from other substantiations.
Resulting pattern I came to:

```
[
    get_package_share_directory('robot_bringup'),
    '/urdf/',
    LaunchConfiguration('urdf'),
]
```

List of substantiations is considered as substantiation itself.
Put this wherever you want to use string with LaunchConfiguration and replace `/` with `os.path.sep` if you still want to.
Values in list are merged without any spaces or other symbols and you may use either LaunchConfiguration, strings or another launch.substantions as list members.

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2019-11-22**:
@Dmitriy thanks a lot! Works beautifully. I'll close the answer with due credits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fix by @Dmitriy integrated into my launch script.

```
def generate_launch_description():

   return launch.LaunchDescription([

    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'urdf',
        default_value='file.urdf',
        description='urdf file name'),
   
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package="robot_state_publisher", node_executable="robot_state_publisher", node_name="state_publisher",
            output="screen",
            arguments=[[get_package_share_directory('robot_bringup'), '/urdf/', LaunchConfiguration('urdf') ]]),

    ])
```

---

Originally posted by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) with karma: 131 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2020-05-14**:
Hi @Dmitriy @fastestindian
Would you be so kind to share one full example for launching a xacro file and running robot_state_publisher?